# Invalid icon file located in 'application folder'

Tags: visual-studio-2010

in my Setup project i delete icon and add new one now when i build the setup project i have this error

**Invalid icon file xxx located in 'application folder'**

i use VS 2010

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I think this might help you:

Add a valid icon in the Project. Then left click to select the installer project (in solution explorer). Go to properties window, change the **AddRemoveProgramsIcon**. Browse and set it to the newly added valid icon.

Comment: Note: To open properties window, select the project (in solution explore) and use the menu: "View / Properties Window"

Comment: Shortcut to open properties window is select the project in solution explore and press F4

Comment: +1 Aarghh I was staring at those properties looking for an "Icon" property, never saw "AddRemoveProgramsIcon"

Answer (score 9):

Alternately, just change the AddRemoveProgramsIcon value to "None" in your install project, if you are not ready to specify an icon file yet.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue, I had the icon in my application folder, I saw it in the explorer, everything looked fine, but I was having problems with **TFS**, going back and forward then the problem appeared, what I did was the following:

1. Went to my Setup project properties and on the **AddRemoveProgramsIcon** property clicked on **Browse**, then saw that the file name was there but not the physical icon as in the image below

[image: No physical icon]

2. Click on browse and searh in the Application Folder for my icon, then inserted it as, then saw the physical icon as in the image below

[image]
[image]

3. Then rebuild and everything was ok

Comment: Restart as well!

Comment: no joy here. This used to be so easy to do, but anytime I add an icon to this "folder", I get the error here. (VS2019 and the latest and greatest setup projects - this worked before, not sure why it no longer works)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using that icon for shortcuts, if so you have to re-affect all shortcuts to the new icon, same thing when you delete an assembly & even if you replace it with a new one with the same name you have to **re-affect all**

Answer (score 1):

Use a different icon and rebuild the project again. It seems to get stuck if you use a different name. Alternatively you can also close the solution and reopen it again to clear the error.