# I can't get Visual Studio community 2022 to create a setup.exe program

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Several months ago, for a Visual Basic desktop app, I used Visual Studio Community 2022 version (17.8.3) to create a `setup.exe` program.

I've just tried to re-create the `setup.exe` file, and I did not know that `VisualStudioSetup.exe` would download the latest version of the installer program (3.9.2164.57262).

I tried to generate the setup program several times, using my 3 pages of instructions, but each time it failed with the message:

```
ERROR: Invalid icon file.
```

Using a different `IconFile.ico` did not solve the problem.

Replacing the program's icon file also did not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182820/invalid-icon-file-located-in-application-folder

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i found the problem .. sort of
the (256x256) icon i have been using for a couple of years no longer works .. when i switched to a new (16x16) icon the installer created a (setup.exe) without any trouble .. jerry